# Error installing psycopg2==2.6.2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have problems when I try installing psycopg2==2.6.2. I have installed postgresql 9.6. and I am using a virtualenv. Any help is welcome.

```
Collecting psycopg2==2.6.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))
  Downloading psycopg2-2.6.2.tar.gz (376kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 378kB 281kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '10.0'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-k7nulk7r/psycopg2/
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed postgresql 9.6? The error message suggests that you have installed 10.0. You should try installing the latest release - 2.6.2 was released over a year ago, long before 10.0 was released.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is [a bug in psycopg2 2.6](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/489). The bug was fixed in psycopg2 2.7. Install the latest version to work with PostgreSQL 10.

Comment: For more information on why it broke, see my [post on psycopg2](https://oshanebailey.jamaicandevelopers.com/python/error-could-not-determine-postgresql-version-10-0/)

Comment: I got the same bug, but I had installed version 9.6 not 10 - so how was that possible? Tom

Comment: The original poster also thought he has installed Pg 9.6. :-)

Comment: yes, your'e right I had two versions installed (and I was just looking at the client version and not the server version)..removing the 10.1 version solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

**The easiest way to fix is to run**

❯ pip install psycopg2-binary